# cron job stopped working after 5 minutes

Tags: php, nginx, cron

Trying to insert several data from one database server to another database server using php script.

Everytime cron job stops execution just after 5 minutes, i already given this

`set_time_limit(0);`

`ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '0');`

`ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`

settings in `php` script.

Also where i can find cron job log in `nginx` server

Comment: What do you mean "stop"? any errors? check logs?

Comment: @sergio cron job doesn't work after 5 minutes

Comment: GIve more info: how you set up cron task, do you enable showing php errors and so on

Comment: also set this on php `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  and cron set like this   `*/10 4-10 * * 3 wget -O - -q -t 1 <file_path> >> <log_file_path>`

Answer (score 0):

cron jobs typically don't have access to environment variables, such as $PATH. Possibly it cannot find the wget binary, and thus the cron job fails.

Try replacing 'wget' in your cronjob with the fully qualified path, such as */usr/bin/wget*

To find the location of wget on your system, use the command 'which':

```
which wget
```